# Dictonary comphrension of another dictonary to calcualte average of list values

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dictonary like -

```
d = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 9], 'c': [1, 3, 9, 8]...}
```

I want to have a new dictonary which will be

```
r = {'a': 2, 'b': 6.5, 'c': 5.25}
```

which are average of list items. I want to do that in a dictonary comprehension code.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
Each of the steps is a trivial browser search: iterate over a dict, compute a mean, store the value in a new dict.

Comment: @Prune I got it. I was not able to picturise how to do the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
r = {
     k: sum(v) / len(v) 
     for (k, v) in d.items()
}
# {'a': 2.0, 'b': 6.5, 'c': 5.25}
```

Comment: That's the most perfect code I've ever seen in my life.

Comment: Thanks, I used `mean()` function.